# Is there any way to merge two worlds in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Is there any way to merge two worlds? Like take chunks from World A, and put them somewhere in World B?

Answer (score 11):

With external programs like [MCEdit](http://www.mcedit.net) you can copy parts of your world to files and then import them into the other world.

Comment: According to the developers, MCEdit only works up to Minecraft 1.11. [MCA Selector](https://github.com/Querz/mcaselector) works for all currently (2023) available Minecraft versions (up to 1.20) and is neatly explained in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7vGIsrsqfkg). (I would have posted this as my own answer, however, because this question is "highly active", I am not allowed to, so sorry for slapping it on here as a comment).

Answer (score 3):

The question sounds like you want to overwrite all chunks of world B with all chunks from world A, but nothing else.

In that case you just have to delete the folders "region", "DIM1" and "DIM-1" from the world folder of world B and copy those folders from the world save folder of world A.

But careful, this can have a lot of unexpected side effects. For example you would keep your ender chest from world B, even though it looks like an external inventory like a chest.